# How can i put a table in a function?

Tags: postgresql

```
id_session,x,z,time
1,-10,-10,0
1,-10,-10,1
1,-5,-4,2
```

I have this function:

```
Select x.x,x.z,sum(case when x=nextlat and z=nextlng then 0 else 1 end ) s
From
(    Select x,
            z,
            lead(x,1,-9999) over (order by tempo) nextlat,              
             lead(z,1,-9999) over (order by tempo) nextlng
            from xmltrack where id_session = 1
) x
Group by x.x,x.z
order by s desc
```

How I create a function with id_session as parameter?
Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xmlintersezioni (idsession integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (cx integer, cz integer, cs integer) AS $$
     BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY Select x.x,x.z,sum(case when x=nextlat and z=nextlng then 0 else 1 end ) s
            From 
           (select x,
            z,
            lead(x,1,-9999) over (order by tempo) nextlat,              
             lead(z,1,-9999) over (order by tempo) nextlng
            from xmltrack where id_session = idsession
) x
Group by x.x,x.z
order by s desc;     
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: what's the problem with your xmlintersezioni ?..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming id_session is a custom type -- something like this:

```
create type id_session_type AS <whatever>;

create table xmltrack (
  id_session id_session_type,
  x integer,
  y integer,
  z integer
);
```

In which case, I think all you need to do is use that same datatype in your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xmlintersezioni (idsesssion id_session_type)
```